# Java - How to get email addresses from outlook mail group

Tags: java, outlook, ldap, jakarta-mail

Just wondering how to get the list of mail addresses from Outlook mail group using Java.

eg: we have a mail group #team@company.com, how to get the list of mail addresses from the group.

Comment: Removed thank you note and greeting

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but I do know that JavaMail won't do it.  Perhaps one of the JavaMail [third party products](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html) that use the Microsoft-proprietary MAPI protocol will do it.